# Paypal API Reference transactions Deprecated

Tags: api, paypal

I see that Paypal API Reference Transactions is deprecated https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

It redirects you to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/ but it hardly does the same thing.

If I will like to create an agreement for several purchases but without redirecting you paypal, which paypa api do you think I should use.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution but hasn't found any also.

Answer (score -1):

Express Checkout does deprecated but the Application such Recurring Payment, Billing Agreement and Reference Transaction are still available.